# Altair python slider not working, module 'altair' has no attribute 'param'

Tags: python, slider, altair

I am trying to use a slider on an interactive chart so that certain points are highlighted either red or blue depending on the slider which changes 'count'.

I have these 2 lines:

```
slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=1000, step=1, name='Cutoff ')
selector = alt.param(name='SelectorName', value=700, bind=slider)
```

and then in the chart after the .encode, I have:

```
color=alt.condition(
    alt.datum.count < selector.cutoff,
    alt.value('red'), alt.value('blue')
```

)
lastly after closing the .encode bracket, I have:

```
    .add_params(
   selector
)
```

This is what I saw in the docs so I don't understand why it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to upgrade altair version 4 to version 5.
Version 4 does not have .add_params()

```
!pip install -U altair
```

In my scenario I was using the default google colab environment.